# How to add active class on click and remove active on click

Tags: javascript, accordion

I am creating accordian menu with simple js. How can I add and remove active class on click open/close?

```
<div class="mobile-categories">
    <h4 class="mcategory-toggle">Vehicles</h4>
    <ul class="msub-categories">
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
    <h4 class="mcategory-toggle">Education</h4>
    <ul class="msub-categories">
        <li>Option 10</li>
        <li>Option 20</li>
        <li>Option 30</li>
    </ul>
    <h4 class="mcategory-toggle">Shops</h4>
    <ul class="msub-categories">
        <li>Option 14</li>
        <li>Option 25</li>
        <li>Option 36</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0jc50ye/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method.

```
  $(document).ready(function($) {
                $('.mobile-categories').find('.mcategory-toggle').click(function(){

            var self = $(this);

            //Expand or collapse this panel
            self.next().slideToggle('fast');

            //Remove active class for all element, except the current selected item
            $('.mcategory-toggle').not(self).removeClass('active');

            //Toggle active class for the current element
            self.toggleClass('active');

                  //Hide the other panels
            $(".msub-categories").not(self.next()).slideUp('fast');

                });
      });
```

You can see [**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k1zr5ugr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery toggle class method to your click function:

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

***Add remove class on Click  Using jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
      if($('.box').hasClass('current')){
        $('.box').removeClass('current');
      }else{
        $('.box').addClass('current');
      }
   });
 });
```

Comment: Think this one is understandable due to the title but I'd recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . even a short well-thought-out sentence can make the question much easier to understand.